# Disable Textbox once its value store in DB - PHP

Tags: php

I have one table and inside that one textbox(to update some value) for each table row. A user will update the value and submit it to the DB. But here, this particular table will show multiple row entries datewise. So, I want to do something like where if a user has submitted one particular rows textbox value that particular textbox should be disabled and the user will not be able to change the same value in future. I need a help I don't understand how to restrict a textbox to do this.

My Code:
I was just able to create a textbox field and call the DB value which is already submitted.

```
 echo "<td> <input pattern='.{9}' id='test' class='c-font-sm' value='$row[rdocket]' name='p_$row[id]'></input> </td>"

 <button  type='submit'  name='submit' class='btn c-theme-btn c-btn-square c-btn-uppercase c-btn-bold'>Submit</button>
```

Any Help???

Comment: Can more than one user edit that row?

Comment: yes. these are independent rows.

Comment: Should it restrict editing to once per user or once in total?

Comment: once per total; it should restrict to only those textbx which value is already submitted in DB. There will be more other txtboxes with no values. using if condition it is restricting to all txtboxes

Comment: Add another column, like `updated`, which is null as default and set it with a timestamp or something when the row is updated. When you then output the input-field, just add "readonly" if `updated` isn't null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
if the data is in the database we display an input with no name and id and set an attribute to readonly (no changes will affect this input if the user submit the form)

```
if((isset($row['rdocket'])) && ($row['rdocket'] != NULL)){
echo "<td> <input pattern='.{9}' class='c-font-sm' value='$row[rdocket]' readonly></input> </td>";
}
else
{
echo "<td> <input pattern='.{9}' id='test' class='c-font-sm' value='$row[rdocket]' name='p_$row[id]'></input> </td>";
}
```

Comment: You should really quote the keys in arrays (when not in a double quoted string): `$row['rdocket']`. You also need to end your echo row with `;` or you will get syntax errors.

Comment: This is somewhat correct. But in DB there are already some Null Values for those textboxes which has not filled by user. By this logic we will be restricting that null values too.

Comment: `input` is more efficient to be defined as `<input .....attributes ... />`

Comment: @skk You just need to eliminate null values from the if statement, i modified the code and corrected the syntax.

Comment: `$row['rdocket'] != "NULL"` doesn't check if a value isn't `null`. It checks if a value doesn't contain the literal string `'NULL'`. Also, `isset()` already does this. It checks if a variable is defined and isn't null so the extra check isn't necessary.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for the details, well, that was only what i could have thought as a solution, he just needs to make it works for him (more or less :p)